# Spinner showing items as Drop Down List

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have made a spinner in an activity getting called inside a tab layout.
 The problem is that the items (3 in nos.) are being showing in a separate dialog as in case of a drop down list and not as a spinner. 
I followed [this](https://mytutorialonline.com/android/spinner) example. And as shown the picture I was expecting
 [image: this]
 but I am getting this:
 [image: this]
 
& this 
[image: this].
 I want to show just 3 items inside the spinner and do not want the new dialog for the items to be selected. And I have tried my code both on 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 emulators. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your targetSDK should be set to higher API level may be latest 16 or 17 whichever u have but above 12 for the spinner to appear as a dropdown and not as a dialog for selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spinner as a dropdown is of HOLO Theme. first image is of HOLO Theme and 2nd and 3rd is not.. holo theme is supported since api level 11..

if you want to apply Holo Theme. set

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and **styles.XML** inside **values-v11** folder

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

and **styles.XML** inside **values** folder

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>


 <style name="progressbar_holo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
</style>
```

and in **AndroidMeanifeast.xml**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in **application** TAG.

**OR**
follow this 2 links
1. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere
2. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Thanks for replying. My current target SDK is 10 and higher SDK is 15 and minimum is 8. But it won't look the same on the 2.3.3 (i.e. SDK version 10) in the emulator if I change my target SDK to a newer version. Is there any way I can bind the `HOLO` theme in my application? So that if a user opens it on the 2.3.3 platform he experiences the exact same UI ?

Comment: Yeah.. sadly looks like there is no other way except than to raise my target SDK version. Marking yours as Answer. Thanks :D

Comment: and upvote my answer.. so others can use this information :-D

Comment: see my edited answer .... i have found this to apply HOLO theme in 2.2 and 2.3 also..

Comment: Thanks again! Well I don't want to include any external libraries(the above link example uses 2)  for now (unless extremely required).

Comment: @SanketKachhela Hi, seemed you've posted two same links and the link of HoloEverywhere has expired

Comment: those links 404; darn it

Comment: This may be useful for those who need the link of HoloEverywhere.
https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere