# Dropdown mode for spinner in android 2.3.3 and higher

Tags: android, android-spinner

HIeveryone!
I looked through other question on this subject byr didn't find a comprehensifve answer. So, I'm asking again. My app must work on android 2.3.3 and higher. I have a spinner and adapter for showing data through it. I want to show data list in dropdown manner when user tapping on spinner. I really don't understand how I should achieve this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _messageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.message_filter_spnStatus);

    ArrayList<String> messageStatuses = new ArrayList<String>();
    messageStatuses.add("All");
    messageStatuses.add("Unread");
    messageStatuses.add("Read");

    _messageSpinner.setAdapter(new MessageStatusAdapter(messageStatuses));
}

public class MessageStatusAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<String> mMessageStatuses = new ArrayList<String>();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        public MessageStatusAdapter(ArrayList<String> messageStatuses)
        {
            mMessageStatuses = messageStatuses;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {                       
            return mMessageStatuses.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final TextView filterName;

            if (convertView == null) {
              filterName = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner_message_status, parent, false);
            } else {
              filterName = (TextView) convertView;
            }

            filterName.setText("StatusTest");
            return filterName;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
          public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final TextView filterName;
            if (convertView == null) {
              filterName = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner_message_status_dropdown, parent, false);
              //filterName.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            } else {
              filterName = (TextView) convertView;
            }

            filterName.setText("DropDownItem");
            return filterName;
          } 

    }
```

item_spinner_message_status:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="@color/text_gray" >
</TextView>
```

item_spinner_message_status_dropdown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvMessageStatusDropdown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_messageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.message_filter_spnStatus);
String[] messageStatuses = { "All", "Unread", "Read" };
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, messageStatuses);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
_messageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Try this code snippet inside your `onCreate()`

Comment: I'm afraid your recipe doesn't work I want it to work. I wrote before that I need dropdown list when user taps on spinner (not "dialog" on the center of the screen). Which version of sdk you use? I need it to work in API 10 and higher.

Comment: I've created simple app that has spinner only and its adapter. It works in dropdown mode "fromthebox" with android starting from 3.0 or API 11. This project by default contains folders "values-v11" and "values-v14" both containing file "styles.xml" which has theme description. May be there is some way to apply these themes on android 2.3.3?

Comment: I read this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214001/spinner-showing-items-as-drop-down-list) where author suggests to use library that provides HOLO theme on API 7 and higher, here it is [link](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). It might be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can override `public boolean performClick ()` method of the Spinner to display a `ListPopupWindow`. This will display a drop down list similar to a ICS styled spinner.

You can set your `MessageStatusAdapter` using the `setAdapter` method of the `ListPopupWindow` object.

You should take care of displaying and dismissing the drop down list using relevant methods, like, `setOnItemSelectedListener` or `setOnItemClickListener` of  the ListPopupWindow object.